# encodeURI equivalent needed not URLEncoder.encode that is equivalent to encodeURIComponent()

Tags: java, urlencode

Kindly let me know the `encodeURI()` in JavaScript equivalent in Java.

Though am aware of this equivalent to `encodeURIComponent()`.

```
result = URLEncoder.encode(component, "UTF-8")
    .replaceAll("\\%28", "(") 
    .replaceAll("\\%29", ")") 
    .replaceAll("\\+", "%20") 
    .replaceAll("\\%27", "'") 
    .replaceAll("\\%21", "!") 
    .replaceAll("\\%7E", "~");"
```

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, just flag such things from next time. No need to comment. Otherwise your comment will be meaningless when the stuffs are removed by moderators :)

Comment: It was a fun response to Andrew's comment, I wasn't the first one to comment. But I'll happily remove the comment now that Andrew's is gone.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this;

```
    public static String encodeURIComponent(String url) {
        try {
            return URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8")
                .replaceAll("\\+", "%20")
                .replaceAll("\\%21", "!")
                .replaceAll("\\%27", "'")
                .replaceAll("\\%28", "(")
                .replaceAll("\\%29", ")")
                .replaceAll("\\%7E", "~");
            //the slow option:
            //new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript")...etc
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            //never
        }
    }

    public static String encodeURI(String url) {
            return encodeURIComponent(url)
                .replaceAll("%3A", ":")
                .replaceAll("%2F", "/")
                .replaceAll("%3F", "?")
                .replaceAll("%3D", "=")
                .replaceAll("%26", "&");
    }
```

More work would be needed to ensure it supports nesting and the full specification.